# Optimized way to create relationship between millions of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have nodes  uploaded to neo4j and each of the nodes have properties like `email`, `phone`, `address`, etc. I need to create relationship between two nodes if sum of levenshtein distance between properties of nodes is less than a threshold value. How to do this in more optimized way? Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
MATCH (p1:sample500K) WITH p1 
MATCH (p2:sample500K)
WHERE id(p1) <id(p2)
AND (
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(p1.email, p2.email) + 
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(p1.phone, p2.phone) + 
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(p1.mobilephone, p2.mobilephone) +
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(p1.street, p2.street)) <= $threshold
MERGE (p1)-[:SAME_USER500K]->(p2)
```

I have also tried with apoc.periodic.iterate which also taking time. Also, I need to run the query in python.

Can someone suggest a better method or any changes if needed to make?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamentally exponentially hard problem; more input data will result in way more possibilities to check with brute force like approaches.

Therefore I would suggest splitting your approach in two steps:

1. Generate a vector representation from your input data. My own search showed that you can pass your string input data to n-gram frunctions to get small chunks of the original string, which you can then pass to a tf-idf function to get an actual vector. Do that for all your input params, make sure that the vectors are always the same length, merge them and put them in a vector database.
2. Execute a vector similarity search inside your vector database to get similar records, which might fulfill your levenshtein-distance requirements. Then check your requirement for every returned element in a brute force like fashion.

This approach should drastically reduce the amount of checks you would have to do, but requires a vector database. I think Neo4j has basic vector capabilities, but I am not sure how good they are. The key aspect is the vector similarity search itself.

Note: The n-gram-data to vector step might not be consistent if some n-gram-fragment is not part of another n-gram-result. This might require some testing or more standardization, not sure.

Comment: will there be any other way to create relationship with these conditions?

Comment: @cheesebutter you always have the option to brute force a solution. But this takes time. E.g. you have one million nodes in your database, then you must test one trillion comparisons. If you can compare 10.000 nodes per second, this would take around 3 years to compute.

Comment: edit: half a trillion comparisons are needed (1 million x 1 million x 0.5). though this would still take a huge amount of time on a single machine, or many machines a shorter time

Comment: can we achieve this by node embedding or is it entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

Sub or nested queries usually run faster.Something like ...

```
MATCH (p1:sample500K) WITH collect(p1) as pp1
unwind pp1 as x
call
{
  with x
  MATCH (p2:sample500K)
  WHERE id(x) <id(p2)
AND (
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(x.email, p2.email) + 
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(x.phone, p2.phone) + 
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(x.mobilephone, p2.mobilephone) +
  apoc.text.levenshteinDistance(x.street, p2.street)) <= $threshold
MERGE (x)-[:SAME_USER500K]->(p2)
}
```

It might run faster with a double nesting?

Comment: this doesn't reduce the timing to desired extent. Is there any other way to build relationship with gds libarary? I saw knn method to create relationship. But that only comparing the node properties of type numeric. Is there any way to do the same for string type properties?